# Type is not checking for any type

Tags: typescript

I have some example code here:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    buz: string;
}
const fooList: Foo[] = [
    { bar: '1', buz: '1' },
    { bar: '2', buz: '2' }
];
const newList: Foo[] = fooList.map((foo: Foo) => ({
    bar: foo.bar,
}));
```

As expected, here I will have an error `Property 'buz' is missing in type '{ bar: string; }'`.

But if I change type of `fooList` to `any` TS start to thinks that everything is fine:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    buz: string;
}
const fooList: any = [
    { bar: '1', buz: '1' },
    { bar: '2', buz: '2' }
];
const newList: Foo[] = fooList.map((foo: Foo) => ({
    bar: foo.bar,
}));
```

In second case, I expected same error as in the first case. Why TS doesn't throw an error in the second case?

Comment: you explicitly tell the compiler that `fooList` is of type `any`. After that all typing checks are off because from the compiler's point of view `fooList` could be any type you wish.

Comment: Yes, `fooList` can be any type, but `newList` must be `Foo[]` type.

Comment: the type any is also Foo[] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fooList` is of type `any` the compiler also cannot infer anything about the function `fooList.map` (remember it no longer even knows `fooList` is an array).

Therefore it does not know what `map` returns, nor what it does with the delegate you passed in to `map`. It doesn't know that the result of your delegate will be returned from `map` as an element in an array, which means it doesn't know that the result of your delegate is meant to be of type `Foo`, and therefore it doesn't know to warn you that it isn't a valid `Foo`.

If you set `fooList` to type `any[]` instead of `any` then the compiler will know that it is an array, will know about the behaviour of the function `fooList.map`, and will give you the expected error.

Alternatively you could explicitly tell it that your delegate should return a `Foo`:

```
const newList: Foo[] = fooList.map((foo: Foo): Foo => ({
    bar: foo.bar,
}));
```

Which will also allow it to give you the expected error while keeping `fooList` as type `any`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `any` is special. The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) says that it's a way to

> opt-out of type-checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks.

So if you declare something as `any`, you can assign anything to it, assign it to anything, access any property of it, call any method of it and the compiler will not complain, and infer the `any` type for the result of any such operation.

If you omit type annotation for `newList` in the second example, you will see that it's type is inferred as `any`, so it's assignable to `Foo[]`.